# Watched folders in Chrome Apps?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have never coded an app for Chrome, but a use case that I have in mind would probably be best addressed by this kind of solution. A crucial feature though for my app would be to be able to watch a user-specified folder for incoming items. Can this be achieved in Chrome Apps?

Comment: With [fileSystem API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-requestFileSystem) it seems doable. See also a [sample app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/storage).

Comment: Only with [fileSystemProvider](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystemProvider) on Chrome OS.